# Copy folder structure, but latest file only

Tags: powershell, batch-file, robocopy

I have many numbered directories, each containin a set of files:

```
Folder_abc  
   index.xml
   000001.doc
   000002.doc
   000003.doc
   000004.doc

Folder_bdf
   index.xml
   000001.xls
   000002.xls 

Folder_...
```

DESIRED RESULT (latest version only)

```
Folder_abc
  index.xml
  000004.doc
Folder_bdf
  index.xml
  000002.xls 
Folder_...
```

There is an `index.xml` in each directory, *this of course could be copied with `robocopy`, seperately if necessary*.

I am looking for a solution in [powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell) or [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), perfect would be to use [robocopy](/questions/tagged/robocopy), though I don't see an approach.

Comment: This cannot be done with a single command line, you have to write a script for that; perhaps try: `for /D %%D in ("Folder_*") do @((for /F "delims= eol=|" %%F in ('dir /B /A:-D /O:D "%%~D\*.*"') do set "FILE=%%F") & 2> nul md "Destination\%%~nxD" & copy "index.xml" "Destination\%%~nxD\" & call copy "%%~D\%%F" "Destination\%%~nxD\")` (use `/O:N` instead of `/O:D` when you want the source file with the greatest number rather than the most recently modified one)...

Comment: What have you tried? I'm sure this could be accomplished in PowerShell, and relatively confident that it could be done in a batch file, but I wouldn't know how to do it in batch. Show us what you've done to try, and how it is failing, and we can help fix things.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "latest version"? are all of the files different versions of the same file? is the filename representative of its version? are you just looking for the most recently created/modified non `index.xml` file?

Comment: as others have asked - how do you determine "latest version"? by the number in the `.BaseName`? by the last modified timestamp? by the creation time stamp?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the most recenr file couldbe an arbitrarynumber of days old?  Is that true?

If all of your directories are only 1 layer deep on a single root folder, then:

```
 @(
   SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
   Echo Off
 )
 SET "_Root=C:\Some\Folder\Path"
 SET "_NewRoot=C:\Some\New\Folder"

 For /D %%A In ("_Root") Do (
   MD "%_NewRoot%\%%A"
   Copy  "%_Root%\%%A\index.xml" "%_NewRoot%\%%A\index.xml"
   For /F "Tokens=*" %%a IN ('DIR /A-D /B /OD "_Root\%%A\" ^| FindStr /I /V /C:"index\.xml$"') Do (
     SET "_File=%%a"
   )
  Copy  "%_Root%\%%A\!_File!" "%_NewRoot%\%%A\!_File!"
)
```

So, essentially, we need to loop the directory structure and set the value od the _File variable to the files found and, if we order them by date in ascending order, the last value found will he the newest folder, so when we kick out of that loop the variable has been populated with the value you need.

since index is always needed I create the folders and copy index right away and do the second file copy only after a match is found we do ignore "Index.xml" as its already copied and not an appropriate newest file to match anyway

Answer (score 0):

This is basically the code from [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56842143/copy-folder-structure-but-latest-file-only#comment100236375_56842143) as an answer with some explanatory remarks and a minor correction, namely excluding `index.xml` from the files processed by the inner loop:

```cmd
@echo off
rem // Define constants here:
set "ROOT=D:\Path\To\Source"
set "DEST=D:\Path\To\Destination"
set "NAME=Folder_*"  & rem // (name/mask of source sub-directories)
set "FILE=index.xml" & rem // (name of file that must always be copied)

rem // Loop over all sub-directories in the root source directory:
for /D %%D in ("%ROOT%\%NAME%") do (
    rem // Reset variable that will hold name of file to copy later:
    set "LAST="
    rem /* Get all files in sorted manner, except the one that must always be copied;
    rem    store the name in a variable, which will hold the last file name finally;
    rem    `/O:D` regards the last modification date; add `/T:C` for the creation date;
    rem    to sort by name rather than by date, replace `/O:D` by `/O:N` or `/O:NE`: */
    for /F "delims= eol=|" %%F in ('
        2^> nul dir /B /A:-D /O:D "%%~D\*.*" ^| findstr /I /V /C:"%FILE%"
    ') do set "LAST=%%F"
    rem /* Create destination sub-directory with the same name as the source sub-directory;
    rem    potential error message in case the sub-directory already exists are suppressed: */
    2> nul md "%DEST%\%%~nxD"
    rem // Copy the file that always needs to be copied, if there is such:
    if exist "%%~D\%FILE%" copy /-Y "%%~D\%FILE%" "%DEST%\%%~nxD\"
    rem // Copy the previously determined last file, if any has been found:
    if defined LAST call copy /-Y "%%~D\%%LAST%%" "%DEST%\%%~nxD\"
)
```